# Read php file if I am in a folder

Tags: php

I created a footer.php file:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer-col col-md-5">
        <p>Copyright © 2018 Nens Events.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`
```

and it is located on a folder like this one: 
    `/php/footer.php`
All I want is to read it on a subfolder like this one: `/events/na/1.php`

but when I use this code, it doesn't read the footer.php file, does someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("/php/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Any errors? If not try include instead.

Comment: Perhaps looking for: `require_once('/php/footer.php');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `include()` or `require()` function to join your codes into your script.

So the code for reading(in your terms) will be like this
        `<?php include 'php/footer.php'; ?>`

If the site is on root page, use absolute path like this.
`<?php include '/php/footer.php'; ?>`

It should work! Give a try.

Use `require('php/footer.php')` for better coding.